# How to control what part of a UIView to update (iOS/Xamarin) - I need to prevent the screen from being fully erased

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, redraw

I am working on a graphing application which takes in a stream of data and displays it.  It turns out that drawing a lot of line segments in UIView (Core Graphics) is a very slow.  I'm trying to speed it up by only drawing a portion of the screen that has new data.

I currently use this function to redraw the screen (using Xamarin/monotouch)

```
        NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (0.1), delegate {
            pane.SetNeedsDisplay ();
        });
```

where pane is my UIView object.  The pane object knows itself what part of the screen needs to be redrawn.  I think there's another method that specifies a region of the screen to redraw - is that the right way to go?  Or some other solution?

Also, the code draws a set of grids.  These never change.  Is there a way to save them to some layer or something so that I can just add it to the background?

The alternative is to go with openGL though drawing lines doesn't look as good and I'll have to implement a lot of extra code to make it look right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the graph data, you should be using CoreGraphics directly to render the lines in your UIView subclass' `drawRect:` method. Make sure that method only redraws the data that overlaps with the CGRect argument. The method `setNeedsDisplay` marks the entire UIView as needing a redraw, so instead of using that when your graph data changes, you should use the UIView's method `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to indicate that there's new data in that region of the UIView  that will call `drawRect:` to be called, which will only redraw that portion (if you've implemented it right).

Regarding the background grid, you can render the grid to a UIImage then display that UIImage behind your view that draws the graph. You'll want to look at the documentation for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, `CALayer renderInContext:`, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.

Comment: would I need to somehow specify that my UIView has a transparent background?

Comment: Yes, for the UIImageView to show through. You should be able to do this by calling `[super drawInRect:rect];` from your `drawInRect:` method, and making sure to set the background color of the UIView to `[UIColor clearColor];` when it's initialized. You may also need to set the opaque BOOL property to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this variant:

```
void SetNeedsDisplayInRect (RectangleF rect);
```

That will only request that the specified region be redrawn.